# Why is the "top" command showing a CPU usage of 799%?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, multi-core, top

I am running a process in a 4 core Ubuntu server. However, the [`top`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html) command shows that the CPU usage is 799% all the time.

How can this be possible? I know for multi-core CPUs, more than 100% CPU usage is expected, but 799% is a really high value.

Can anybody explain to me why and when this could happen?

As per suggestion of Gregory MOUSSAT, using [`htop`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/htop.1.html), I got the following output:

[image: htop screenshot]

Comment: Do the 4 cores have 2 threads each (e.g. Intel Core i7)?

Comment: @Renan, I am running it on single thread.

Comment: OK, then. Because I have seen this happen on some i7 systems.

Comment: You are absolutely sure that the process you're running is single-threaded?

Comment: @DanielBeck, yah because I code it. And a simple java code.

Comment: But is the *JVM* single-threaded?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, that I really don't know. How to find that ?

Comment: This really looks like a fully loaded i7, I usually get this when encoding video

Comment: Same happens on Raspberry Pi 2 with the new Quad Core ARM. `htop` not installed by default with Raspbian but it looks nicer than `top`.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The scale used by `top` is 100% when a core is fully used. Or when one core is 20% and a second one is 80%. This leads to strange results on multicore computers because it easily can exceed 100%.

If you have 8 cores, then `top` can display CPU usage from 0% (idle system) to 800% (full power).

Your program is just using your 4 cores with hyper-threading (so 8 virtual cores) at maximum capacity. So `top` gives you nearly 8 x 100% = 800%.

To change this way of calculating CPU usage ([it's called Irix mode](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34435/top-output-cpu-usage-100#34436)), press uppercase 'i': <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>

You can't explicitly tell the JVM to use a single thread, it will use multiple threads to do its work, even if you only use a single thread in your application.

You can use the [`htop`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/htop.1.html) utility as a better `top` alternative. You'll see your program using all of the 8 cores.

Comment: You can limit any set of processes to a set of cores or limit the % of cpu. However I don't remember the commands. (one is cpulimit)

Comment: Why is htop reporting 300% CPU usage on one thread?