# How to troubleshoot high cpu problems related to postgres and postmaster service?

Tags: linux, memory

I'm using an open source(RHCE 6.2) based machine running SIEM software , when i do the top command i see

> postgress
>   postmaster

both eating 96% of cpu usage? Is there a way to pin-point or see what causing these service to stack up?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not necessarily a problem. If both processes are shown at 96%, you have a multi-core processor. By default, `top` runs in "Irix mode" which means that it shows CPU usage as a percentage of a single core. That's why multiple processes can be shown as running at 100%.

To disable this and see the percentage of total CPU usage, hit <kbd>Shift</kbd> +<kbd>i</kbd> while `top` is running. For more information on `top` and the information it displayes, see my answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/575330/151431).