# Monitoring CPU usage of Virtualbox with top

Tags: linux, virtualbox, cpu-usage, top

I'm using the `top` command in Linux to keep a close eye on Virtualbox which is running a VM.

The current CPU in the server is a Quad Core Xeon processor 3.3 Ghz and I have only assigned one core to the VM.

My question is, if `top` is reporting that the Virtualbox process is consuming 30 percent of the CPU is this for the single core I have assigned the VM or for all 4 cores?

If VB is consuming 30 percent of the entire CPU I think I may need to assign more cores to VB. Clients are reporting that their client machines freeze constantly when accessing the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `top` reports the percentage use as a percentage of a **single** CPU. This has nothing to do with your VirtualBox settings, it is how `top` works and it is the same for all programs. That's why you often see >100% CPU usage in `top`. Have a look at my answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/575330/151431) for more details.

You can have `top` display CPU% as a percentage of total CPU power (all cores) by hitting <kbd>I</kbd> (that's capital I) while `top` is running.

---

EDIT to answer your comments:

1. *So if all 4 cores max out I would see cpu usage rocket to 400 percent?*

   Yes, exactly.
2. *And if I'm seeing a total of 30 percent usage amongst all processes does that mean only 30 percent of a single core?*

   <del>Again, yes, exactly.</del> Well, almost exactly. It is not 30% of a single core because different processes can be running on different cores. If you see a total of 30% usage, this means that the total processing power being used is the equivalent of 30% of a single core. This might mean that you have one core at 10%, two at 5% and one at 20%.
3. *And I also guess that this wouldn't actually reflect the CPU usage of the VM running under VB?*

   Not sure what you mean here. The % usage of VirtualBox in `top` is how much of a *single* core is VBox using at that moment. This has nothing to do with how much of the virtual machine's *virtual* CPU is being used. To see that, you will need to use software running on the guest OS.

Comment: So if all 4 cores max out I would see cpu usage rocket to 400 percent?

Comment: And if im seeing a total of 30 percent usage amongst all processes does that mean only 30 percent of a single core?

Comment: And I also guess that this wouldn't actually reflect the CPU usage of the VM running under VB?

Comment: @Scandalist I updated my answer to address your comments.

Comment: This is a great answer

Comment: @Scandalist I made an important clarification to my answer to your 2nd comment, you might want to read it again.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the host system, [VBoxManage metrics](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#metrics) is easy to use:

```
vboxmanage metrics setup --period 1 --samples 1 "*" "*CPU/*"
```

to configure which metrics will be captured and for which system/VM.

Then:

```
vboxmanage metrics collect "*" "*CPU/*:avg"
```

will show you the aggregates of processor usage on the host and by each running VM.

Note that in order to see `Guest/*` stats you might need to have installed *Guest Additions* on each VM.